# Remove any CSS file within <body> with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Simple question really. I want to immediately remove any CSS file **within* the **body*** of any page on my website, and **then proceed to load** the page as usual.

How do I do this?

Comment: Given your question you should do it on server-side

Comment: I don't have access to that per my provider. Only can upload files to head.

Comment: You should explain what is actually happening. If that's *your website* - than I would simply open my own files and prevent that from happening by removing any inline or *"off-head"* `<style>`s. Otherwise `$("body").find("style").remove()` would do what you asked. PS: find a provider that does not embeds `style` in your `body`.

Comment: I want to remove this reoccuring CSS file that is contained on every single page: <div><link rel="stylesheet" id="dynamic-style" type="text/css" href="https://style.realgeeks.media/templates/miranda-thin.css"></div>

Comment: But the file name is different on each page, really strange. That's why I'm asking how to remove any CSS file that is contained within the body on each page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body style').remove();
```

Should do the job, but it really depends on what you mean by "and then proceed to load the page as usual". Your javascript won't be executed until the HTML is parsed and the browser has already started applying the CSS. However removing the tags as above should remove any styles applied by those tags, but there may be a flicker of those styles before your javascript is loaded.

This is very unlikely to be the best way to solve whatever the larger problem you're having is.